# ion-item-sliding is not working with dynamic values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using `<ion-item-sliding>` to show some random values and on sliding want to perform some operation. My code is as below

TS Code

```
getRandomInt(min, max) {
this.number = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  this.number.push({ scripname: 'SBIN' + (i + 1), ltp: number })
}


 }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
      this.getRandomInt(1, 101)
    });
  }
```

Html code

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of number">
  <ion-item>
    {{item.scripname}}
    <ion-badge item-end>{{item.ltp}}</ion-badge>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button color="primary">
      Buy
    </button>
    <button ion-button color="secondary">
      Sell
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

I am getting output as

[image: Output]

when i swipe it show me option but as soon as the value get changed the buttons get disappeared.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when you update the `this.number` property? This behaviour is just normal, because the whole element gets updated when you change it.

Comment: @StephanStrate You are right but can i avoid that? Or is their any other way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could update the badges manually with JavaScript, but this is not a clean solution at all